# Can we compile and sign a windows 8 winjs application via commandline

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, winjs

Is there any way to create a windows 8 winjs .appx package file using command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes! Look for the MSBuild.exe executable in the .NET Framework folder. You run it like:

```
MSBuild.exe your/project.jsproj /p:Configuration=Release /t:Build /m
```

You can use "Debug" instead of "Release" and also "Deploy" instead of build (which will install the app locally, if not previously installed).

More at the [MSBuild reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx).

There are some [usage samples in the Rainbowdriver project](https://github.com/rainbowdriver/rainbowdriver-node/blob/master/lib/builder.js), which uses MSBuild to automatically test Windows 8 JS Apps using Selenium.

Comment: Can you actually sign it from the command line though, for upload to the store? I don't think you can.

Comment: You can, but it's hard. On the team I'm on we used http://www.sikuli.org/ to automate the store submission.

Comment: You can create .appx packages using the `publish` target.  Then you can sign using `signtool`, but I haven't yet found a way to automatically upload the package for store submission.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I am trying to automate the process of building and signing an application. Any other thoughts on this process?